# Why BUILDER Pattern more secure than the javaBean?

Tags: java

As the title, I am reading `<Effective Java>`, but when i read chapter2, it says

Comment: Did your question cut off?  Looks like it was submited before complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When objects are *immutable*, you have much less to worry about than when objects (like JavaBeans) are *mutable*. Once you have an immutable object it is basically immune to thread synchronization problems, and you can freely pass it around without making defensive copies (to protect users or well-intentioned library methods from changing the data).

Naturally, creating a mutable object can be tricky, and may involve constructors far too long to manage. This is where the Builder pattern can help you--use a mutable Builder to create the initial state, then copy it to an immutable object in that object's constructor.

Note that if the immutable object contains references to any mutable objects, the outside object isn't really immutable. You may find `ImmutableList`, `ImmutableMap`, and `ImmutableSet` handy in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

The `Builder` pattern is more secure because the Builder can validate all of the parameters before passing it into the constructor.

You might find `Preconditions` from Google handy for this.

Not to mention, using a Builder makes constructing complex objects very concise.

I wouldnt say that objects following the builder pattern are any more or less `immutable` or mutable then a `JavaBean`. It depends on how you declare fields and what methods you expose.